# Downcast CoreData entities instantiated with MagicalRecord in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, swift, magicalrecord

I have entities prefixed with *ICD_* in my Core Data Model. For each entity, I have a subclass which is prefixed with *CD_*. The subclasses which are prefixed with *CD_* only implement static getters.

When I create an entity with MagicalRecord, I have to use the class prefixed with *ICD_* not with *CD_*. Otherwise, I've got a SIGABRT:

> "+entityForName: could not locate an entity named 'CD_User' in this
>   model."

If I downcast my *ICD_* entity to my *CD_Entity* it works in Objective-C. The same thing in Swift causes a SIGABRT. It's quite naturally because, it's the parent entity which is allocated, not the child class, so it's normally impossible to downcast it.

So I'm looking for a solution which permits to use my subclasses prefixed with *CD_* with MagicalRecord.

Comment: If your `CD_*` subclasses implement static getters and nothing else, then why do you ever need to downcast?

Comment: I agree with you, in Objective-C it works, but in Swift it causes a SIGABRT.

Comment: It sounds like a bug in Obj-C, whereas Swift handles it correctly.

Comment: So if I cast an ICD_ into a CD_ in objective-c and it doesn't crash you think it's a bug ?

Comment: Try using categories instead of subclass to extend your entities.

Comment: I can't because if I regenerate my Core Data entities, I have to reimplement protocol each time, because Core Data override the whole .m file

Comment: Not if you keep the category in a separate source file.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by using "the class prefixed with ICD_". It sounds like ICD_ is just the name of the entity, not a class. Can you give a minimal sample project which produces the error you're seeing?

Comment: @Koen, yes you're right ! Problem solved ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Either your data model is not loaded properly, or you are using an incorrect name to access the entities. You can see what names your data model contains by using the [-entitiesByName method on NSManagedObjectModel](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectModel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001174-BCIGHAIH)

Comment: I know that my entities in the Core Data Model are named with *ICD_* prefix. For example *ICD_User*, *ICD_Basket* and so on... For each of those entities, I have subclasses prefixed with *CD_*. For example: *CD_User*, *CD_Basket*. To create an Entity with MagicalRecord, I have to call the method `MR_createEntity` with the classes prefixed with *ICD_*. But I would like to instantiate *CD_* classes instead of *ICD_* classes. How can I do that using MagicalRecord ?

Comment: So I think, I don't need to use `-entitiesByName` method.